# javascript - problems with constructor

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, constructor, radix

I have a very strange effect in JavaScript

```js
function Enemy(name, x, y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log("create normal");
    //console.log("tworzenie normalnego " + this.name);
}

function EnemyShoot(name, x, y) {
    Enemy.call(this, name, x, y); // call base constructor
    this.type = "shooter";
    console.log("create shooter");
}

EnemyShoot.prototype = Object.create(Enemy.prototype);
EnemyShoot.prototype.constructor = EnemyShoot;

const enemyN = new Enemy("Normal", 5, 0);
const enemyS = new EnemyShoot("Shooter", 10, 20);
```

. Check this out my friends:

Question is - why when I comment `console.log("create normal");` and uncomment next instruction everything is ok, and now is not ok. Now is not ok in my opinion because I have in console:
create normal
create shooter
instead:
create normal
create normal
create shooter

After mentioned changing , everything is ok.

Comment: Switching the two `console.log` lines in the base constructor does not result in the difference you describe (two log lines instead of three).  Are you missing something from your example?

Comment: @Sean-Vieira - I see that no difference here in code snippet but I am testing this in firefox and F12 and console, where I have very strange result as I described.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this:

```
const enemyN = new Enemy("Normal", 5, 0);
```

You cause the `Enemy` constructor to fire and so in the console you get:

```
create normal
```

Then, when you execute this:

```
const enemyS = new EnemyShoot("Shooter", 10, 20);
```

You cause the `EnemyShoot` constructor to fire, which contains a call to `Enemy`, so you get a second `create normal` in the console.

Then, you get the `EnemyShoot` console instruction to execute, so you get `create shooter` in the console as the third line.

Commenting the first `console.log` and uncommenting the one after it simply replaces the first two outputs to show the data relative to the context object, which (because of the `Enemy.call(this, name, x, y)` line, ensures that the second line replaces the `this` context with the context of the inherited instance. This is exactly how it should operate.

```js
function Enemy(name, x, y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log("create normal");
    //console.log("tworzenie normalnego " + this.name);
}

function EnemyShoot(name, x, y) {
    Enemy.call(this, name, x, y); // call base constructor
    this.type = "shooter";
    console.log("create shooter");
}

EnemyShoot.prototype = Object.create(Enemy.prototype);
EnemyShoot.prototype.constructor = EnemyShoot;

const enemyN = new Enemy("Normal", 5, 0);
const enemyS = new EnemyShoot("Shooter", 10, 20);
```

Comment: I understand the theory of these things but I am still confused because when I testing this code into my firefox browser (F12 and console), I have symptoms like I described before. And the worse is that I can not understand why there are.

Comment: @Adamos19 It is not entirely clear exactly what results you are getting with which version of the code and why it is you feel that those results are incorrect.

Comment: because I have in browser output:

Comment: @Adamos19 You have what in the browser output and what do you expect to get?

Comment: nevermind, sorry. Console output is a little strange formatted because I see "create normal" one time, but with 2 times additional information on the right side on this screen. Never mind, now I see and I am sure that system call one constructor and base constructor from inside.